# iterate through multilple jQuery commands for an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

i got the following jQuery stuff where i entered the array numbers and selector positions by feet - can i do this in one block with an for loop?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.hoverB0x:eq(0)').html('<a style="background:white;" class="imageLink" href="${createLink(uri: "/beirat/")}">Profil von' + names[0]+'</a>');
    jQuery('div.name:eq(0)').html(title[0]+' '+names[0]);
    jQuery('div.description:eq(0)').html(funktion[0]);
    jQuery('a.imageLink:eq(0)').prop('href', 'beirat/'+ident[0]);
    jQuery('a.contentLink:eq(0)').prop('href', 'beirat/'+ident[0]);
    jQuery('.profilBildInner:eq(0) img').attr('src', base+ident[0]+'.png');
```

Now about 10 blocks going to follow up with eq([arrayPos]) and names/ident[arrayPos]

Comment: "can i do this in one block with an for loop?" Yes. Use a for loop and replace `:eq(1)` with `:eq(' + i + ')` and `[1]` with `[i]` assuming `i` is your loop index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see why not... just change the indexes to use the increment counter of a `for` loop. You dont show how you get the `names`, `ident`, or `funktion` arrays but presumable they are the same size and hold the proper count of things you expect in the document so use one of those to get your base increment range.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ident.length; i++){
    $('.hoverB0x:eq(' + i + ')').html('<a style="background:white;" class="imageLink" href="${createLink(uri: "/beirat/")}">Profil von' + names[i]+'</a>');
    $('div.name:eq(' + i + ')').html(title[i]+' '+names[i]);
    $('div.description:eq(' + i + ')').html(funktion[i]);
    $('a.imageLink:eq(' + i + ')').prop('href', 'beirat/'+ident[i]);
    $('a.contentLink:eq(' + i + ')').prop('href', 'beirat/'+ident[i]);
    $('.profilBildInner:eq(' + i + ') img').attr('src', base+ident[i]+'.png');

}
```

Further more if possible it would make much more sense to combine those arrays into a a single array of hahses like:

```
var values = [
  {ident: 'ident_value', funktion: 'function_value', name: 'name_value'}
];
```

Then you can do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    $('.hoverB0x:eq(' + i + ')').html('<a style="background:white;" class="imageLink" href="${createLink(uri: "/beirat/")}">Profil von' + values[i].name+'</a>');
    $('div.name:eq(' + i + ')').html(title[i]+' '+values[i].name);
    $('div.description:eq(' + i + ')').html(values[i].funktion);
    $('a.imageLink:eq(' + i + ')').prop('href', 'beirat/'+values[i].ident);
    $('a.contentLink:eq(' + i + ')').prop('href', 'beirat/'+values[i].ident);
    $('.profilBildInner:eq(' + i + ') img').attr('src', base+values[i].ident+'.png');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    $('.hoverB0x:eq(' + i + ')').html('<a style="background:white;" class="imageLink" href="${createLink(uri: "/beirat/")}">Profil von' + names[i]+'</a>');
    $('div.name:eq(' + i + ')').html(title[i]+' '+names[i]);
    $('div.description:eq(' + i + ')').html(funktion[i]);
    $('a.imageLink:eq(' + i + ')').prop('href', 'beirat/'+ident[i]);
    $('a.contentLink:eq(' + i + ')').prop('href', 'beirat/'+ident[i]);
    $('.profilBildInner:eq(' + i + ') img').attr('src', base+ident[i]+'.png');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    jQuery('.hoverB0x:eq(' + i + ')').html('<a style="background:white;" class="imageLink" href="${createLink(uri: "/beirat/")}">Profil von' + names[i] + '</a>');
    jQuery('div.name:eq(' + i + ')').html(title[i] + ' ' + names[i]);
    jQuery('div.description:eq(' + i + ')').html(funktion[i]);
    jQuery('a.imageLink:eq(' + i + ')').prop('href', 'beirat/' + ident[i]);
    jQuery('a.contentLink:eq(' + i + ')').prop('href', 'beirat/' + ident[i]);
    jQuery('.profilBildInner:eq(' + i + ') img').attr('src', base + ident[i] + '.png');
}
```